# How to set the number of showing row in angular2

Tags: angular

Am using AngularJS2. The ng2-smart-table in my project shows 10 rows at a time . Where can I edit the code to reset the number of rows showing in a page from 10 to 25 in ng2-admin. Is it possible or not ?

Comment: Do you want to customize the text which is showing number of record count?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `pager.perPage` in table settings

something like

```
settings = {
columns:[your columns data here],
pager.perPage:25
}
```

[Find full documentation here](https://akveo.github.io/ng2-smart-table/#/documentation)

Comment: it really works..! make little modification to access perPage

pager: {
          display:true,
          perPage:25
        }

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how is it possible to change the text. But you can make this text manually as what you want.

```
pagingCalculation(e, data) {
        let start = data.length > 0 ? e.first + 1 : data.length;
        let end = (e.first + e.rows) > data.length ? data.length : (e.first + e.rows);
        return 'Showing ' + start + ' to ' + (end ? end : 0) + ' of ' + data.length + ' Entries';
    }
```

> The parameter `e` should have current page rows  in `e.rows` object (like 10) and current page number in `e.first` object (like if you are in second page in the pagination, `e.first` value should be 20)